# Replace class using javascript is not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, searchkit

I want to change the class of dynamic element on click function for that I tried below solutions but none of these working

```
  handleClick=(event,headerText)=>{
     document.getElementsByClassName('sk-reset-filters')[0].className = 'jjjj';
  }


 handleClick=(event,headerText)=>{
   var reset = document.querySelectorAll('.sk-reset-filters.is-disabled')[0];
   console.log(reset)
   if(reset){
     reset.className = 'sk-reset-filters';   
     console.log(reset)   
  }
```

I just want to remove the `is-disabled` when click. I also tried using setTimout function but doesn't work. Is there anything wrong?

When I `console.log(reset)` I'm getting below html.

```
<div class="sk-reset-filters is-disabled">
    <div class="sk-reset-filters__reset">Clear all</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your click handler function called when you click the button?

Comment: yes handleclick is called when I click the element

Comment: Does the `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll` return the exact element you're looking for?

Comment: yes wait let me add it to the question. @frogatto I have added in question

Comment: I'm getting full html of that elemt

Comment: Can you create a live demo? jsfiddle.net or SO's code snippet?

Comment: Ok let me make it.

Comment: Also it's more convenient  to use `Element.classList.remove()` function to remove a class from the class list rather than setting `Element.className` directly.

Comment: @frogatto also tried this .remove() not worked. I just added 2nd code from question in jsfiddle. It's working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rh1ns5xg/ you can check here

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fine, what's the problem?

Comment: In my code it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can handle disable or show dom elements with react state in this way:

```
state={isDisabled:true}  // set a state property

handleClick=(e)=>{
e.preventDefault
this.setState({isDisabled:false}) //change !isDisabled to false when clicked
}

render() {
  {isDisabled} = this.state
  let disabledMarkup = isDisabled ? <div>something</div> : null}
  return (<React.Fragment>{disabledMarkup}
  <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
  </React.Fragment>)}
```

Comment: I cant use state because this element comming dynamically from searchkit.

Comment: In this case you should use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) API